# Existe una forma para actualizar los los un campo en especifico en relacion a otra tabla en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, funciones, sql-server-2017, actualizar

Primeramente tenia una tabla donde tenia los datos de mis empleados similar a esto

```
tbl_empleado
  idEmpleado
  Nombre
  Puesto
  Departamento
```

pero tuve la nececidad de realizar otras dos tablas para guardar los departamentos y los puestos haciendo un catalogo por cada una, similar a esto

```
cat_Puesto
  idPuesto
  puesto

cat_departamento
  idDepartamento
  departamento
```

Ahora necesito actualizar mi `tbl_empleado` en los campos **Puesto** y **Departamento** para que éstas sean llaves foraneas.
Alguien tiene una funcion o algo para actualizar esos campos y que se guarden las id de los catalogos?
Hay que considerar en la tbl_empleado los los puestos y departamentos estan guardados en texto y por ejemplo en mi cat_puesto.puesto esta guardado igual.
Yo me imagino algo asi

```
SELECT idpuesto as idp, Puesto as pue FROM cat_puestos 
UPDATE Tbl_Empleados SET Puesto = idp WHERE Puesto = pue
```

el select busca el id y puesto del cat_puesto, esos alias los puse para identificarlos y pasarlos al update donde hace la comparacion, en que si el tbl_empleados.puesto = pues (que es el alias del select )lo actualice con el id que tambien traigo del select

Comment: O ALGO ASI, NO LO SÉ
UPDATE Tbl_Empleados as tble SET 

Puesto = (SELECT id_Puesto from cat_puestos as catp) WHERE tble.Puesto = catp.Puesto

Answer (score 0):

Podes realizar la siguiente query:

```
UPDATE Tbl_Empleados as tble
INNER JOIN cat_puestos as catp
ON tble.Puesto = catp.Puesto
SET tble.Puesto = catp.id_Puesto
```